Dask merge ordered
I have a kind of huge dataset (about 100GB) based on blockchain data. I want to merge two tables based on the transactionHash, which would be impossible (O(n^2)) except because these two tables are both ordered by blockNumber, so this can be done in O(|A|+|B|)=O(n).
The tables would have something like this, among other columns




blockNumber
transactionHash




0
1
0x0


1
1
0x1


2
1
0x6


3
2
0x2


4
2
0x8


5
2
0xf



In pandas, I would use pd.merge_ordered, but it seems this is not available in dask.
blockNumber = [1,1,1, 2,2,2]
transactionHash = ['0x0', '0x1', '0x6', '0x2', '0x8', '0xf']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'blockNumber': blockNumber,
    'transactionHash': transactionHash,
    'field1': [42,37,21,78,32,45],
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'blockNumber': blockNumber,
    'transactionHash': transactionHash,
    'field2': [True, False, True, True, False, False],
})
res1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['transactionHash'])
res2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['blockNumber', 'transactionHash'])
assert res1.equals(res2)

How can I either:

a) Implement this algorithm myself, what should I take into account and how can I "align" partitions
b) Use an alternative with other dask functions


Is the transactionHash key unique?

Yes it is, but it is sorted by blockNumber then transactionHash, because the important thing is the timeSeries. I can use them as an index if I use index=[...] in dd.read_parquet

Can you give an example of the 2 inputs and output on a small dataset with how you would have used pd.merge_ordered?

I've been using merge_ordered thinking that it was like merge but assuming that the data was ordered and thus more efficient. But I realized that it takes even more time than just using merge.

This is because pandas improved the performance of merge on monotonic keys recently https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/56523

I learnt something new! Looks like you (kind of) answered your own question. Feel free to answer and accept your own question. It looks like the PR was added to pandas v2.2.0, which might be worth mentioning.

Hi, if you have the same number of records with the same keys in both Dataframe, you could partition Dataframes by block number, and then just megre each partitions two by two using dask map_partitions.

@GuillaumeEB Thanks, unfortunately, they do not. It seems that merging by index is "merge by order"
